# Passing this and variables to imported function onclick

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am utterly confused by this peice of code, that does not seem to work in any way.
Simply, it's this:

```
// in app.js
import {layoutItemButtonClick} from '/blablaWrappeur.js'
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


    var element = document.querySelector('.qq-element') //this is a html element obj

    $('.layout-item-button').click(layoutItemButtonClick)
})

//in blablaWrappeur.js
export const layoutItemButtonClick = function () {
    const selectedLayout = this.dataset.layout.split("")
    doQqthing(element) // element is not defined

}

function doQqthing(element) {
    alert(element) /// not defined
}
```

I need to pass the element and the this context of the clicked button to the layoutItemButtonClick function and then inside that, to the doQqthing function.

However, it does not work like this.

**1)** If I let the code like this and click the button nothing happens.

**2)** Now, if I change the click function to this (adding paranthese to the function call:

```
$('.layout-item-button').click(function () {
        layoutItemButtonClick()
    })
```

I get a `dataset is not defined` error.

**3)** If I change it to this:

```
 $('.layout-item-button').click(layoutItemButtonClick())
```

I get the same error.

**4)** For this:

```
$('.layout-item-button').click(layoutItemButtonClick)
```

I get an `element is not defined` error.

I know that if I call the function inside a function, *this* would be the current element, and if inside the click parentheses like in 3) and 4), it would be the local scope this. So, how do I pass both the element and the this from the click into my function.

And why/how does using parenthesis make a difference when calling a function defined as a constant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Bergi fixed now! sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And why/how does using parenthesis make a difference when calling a function defined as a constant?

`layoutItemButtonClick` is like any other variable access. It resolves to the value of the variable, which is a function object.

`layoutItemButtonClick()` otoh **calls** the function and resolves to its return value.

Therefore,

```
 $('.layout-item-button').click(layoutItemButtonClick())
```

passes the *return value* of `layoutItemButtonClick` (which is `undefined`) to `.click` whereas

```
 $('.layout-item-button').click(layoutItemButtonClick())
```

passes the function object itself to `.click`.

---

> I get an `element is not defined` error.

And rightly so because `element` is not defined in the scope accessible to `layoutItemButtonClick`. It is only defined inside `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

You'd have to pass `element` as argument to `layoutItemButtonClick`. So the function should be declared as

```
export const layoutItemButtonClick = function(element) { ... }
```

Now we need to call `layoutItemButtonClick` such that `this` refers to the clicked element and we pass `element` as argument. We can do this using `.call`:

```
$('.layout-item-button').click(function() {
    layoutItemButtonClick.call(this, element);
});
```

---

However, there is no need for using `this` inside `layoutItemButtonClick`. We can just make the element that triggered the event an explicit argument:

```
 export const layoutItemButtonClick = function(trigger, element) {
   const selectedLayout = trigger.dataset.layout.split("")
   doQqthing(element);
 };
```

and call it as

```
$('.layout-item-button').click(function() {
    layoutItemButtonClick(this, element);
});
```